# Error Connecting Centos 7 to Android phone with jmtpfs

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, centos7, samsung-galaxy, mtp

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android version 5.0.1 (which is the last version supplied for that phone, apparently). When I run `jmtpfs -l` I get the following (this is CentOS 7):

```
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
Available devices (busLocation, devNum, productId, vendorId, product, vendor):
7, 84, 0x6860, 0x04e8, Galaxy models (MTP), Samsung
```

Then, `jmtpfs -device=7,84 /media/samsung` (with or without sudo and with or without `-o allow_other` ) produces the following error:

```
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
error returned by libusb_claim_interface() = -6LIBMTP PANIC: Unable to initialize device
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MtpErrorCantOpenDevice'
  what():  Can't open device
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The man file for jmtpfs says something about adding a new rule to /lib/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules but that file does not exist and I have no idea what I need to put in that file. Is that my problem?

Is my old Android version to blame or something else? Is there any hope for me?

-- Henry